# VFD IGBT blew up and I can't find a replacement part

Tags: vfd

So here’s my situation, a few weeks ago I received a 2.2kW variable frequency drive from a chinese seller and it worked perfectly. I then watched a video on youtube by AvE where he takes one apart (not the same model). He says that if you want to increase the lifespan on your VFD you should check so there is thermal paste on everything that is in contact with the heatsink. So I take [mine](https://www.ebay.com/itm/220V-2-2KW-CNC-Spindle-motor-speed-control-Variable-Frequency-Drive-VFD-Inverter/262880229538?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2648) apart to apply good thermal paste to it. In between the IGBT’s and the heatsink there are thermal pads (the thermally conductive rubber ones), rather than thermal paste. At the moment I think that's stupid because they do not have as good thermal conductivity as thermal paste. I remove them and apply some thermal paste.

Once I have screwed it back together again, I plug it into the wall and press the start button without having any load on it. I hear a pop and then see an error message on the display. I take it apart again to see that one of the IGBT’s has blown open. My guess is that the IGBT’s weren’t supposed to have electrical contact with the heatsink… Now I'm trying to find a replacement part but I can't find one with the exact same specs as the broken one. [This is the one that was installed](http://www.jiaensemi.com/uploadfile/file/20170310/20170310152818_49584.pdf) on the VFD and blew up.

I'm not an electrician nor have much experience working with IGBT’s. This is the [closest one I could find](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1774719.pdf) on Ebay but the gate-emitter voltage is +- 20V instead of the +- 30V mine is rated for so I’m not sure if it will work.

Does anyone have any suggestions or can provide any help?

(if this does not follow the format of a good question I guess it could be rephrased as “What are the important things to consider when replacing IGBT’s?”)

Comment: If you want to increase the lifespan of your VFDs install a good line reactor on the incoming power supply.  This will eliminate incoming spikes from the utility which damage VFD components.

Comment: You've just removed to electrical insulation pads. With an TO-247 one of the pins is [electrically connected to the exposed pad](http://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/US20130175704A1/US20130175704A1-20130711-D00000.png) used for thermal transfer. You've just shorted all of them to the heatsink.

Comment: AvE is a good guy. He didn't tell you to remove the pads, though, did he? He just said to add the thermal grease?

Answer (score 1):

I would be concerned that the diode junction to case thermal resistance is 2.0 deg C/W for the Fairchild device vs. 0.85 for the original device. In a VFD driving an induction motor the diode carries a significant portion of the current because of the reactive component of the motor current. If you decide to try the Fairchild device, you should probably set the VFD switching frequency to the lowest value.

Trying to improve the life of a product by tinkering with the design is never a good idea. For any electronic product, the best way to improve the life is to try to keep the internal temperature as low as possible. Be careful about mounting it in another enclosure, in a confined space or in direct sunlight. Make sure the space where it is operated is well ventilated. Consider setting the switching frequency to the lowest value, although that may cause the motor to operate at a higher temperature.

Answer (score 1):

This is just my opinion, but if this was a new inverter rated 2.2kW and it is using discrete IGBTs, that is a design that has not been used in mass production for a decade or so. VFD manufacturers in that size range switched to using what are called IPMs (Intelligent Power modules) that house all 6 diodes and 7 IGBTs along with the firing circuits all in one potted device about the size of a credit card. You can't see or replace any individual components in the IPM, nor is it worth messing with because the replacements cost more than an entire new drive. So that means yours is either old stock that was sold as new, which likely explains why you can't find the part, or a very poor design knock-off of a discarded technology.

And that advice you saw on Youtube? Worthless drivel...

Comment: You think adding heatsink compound is worthless drivel? From the OP, it seems that the drive didn't have any heatsink compound.

Answer (score 0):

It's similar, isn't it?

You should be unlikely to fall foul of the max gate voltage. Given the nice tight Vgsth spec of the original, and that it costs power to overdrive a gate, they're unlikely to be deliberately driving more than (say) 15v into it, but the 30v spec on max may mean that they are more lazy on overshoots, so it would be worth measuring. Note the original has an integrated gate resistor, so you would be well recommended to add one of those to tame things.

The original part has a single cycle switching loss of 3.5mJ, compared to 5.06mJ in the replacement. This spec sweeps up a whole bunch of assumptions, but they are taken for the same set of conditions, so are a fair comparison. This means the replacement part could dissipate 50% more power than the original. The thermal resistance junction to case is only 10% less, so the junction is likely to get significantly hotter. Whether the original has enough margin to soak this up without complaint ... ?

The gate charge is higher at 200nC rather than 130nC, which means it would need to be driven harder. With the same drive it will switch slower, which echoes the switching loss comparison.

You might get away with it. As you have a broken VFD, and the replacement costs only a few pounds, it might be worth risking it, perhaps with careful monitoring of the conditions when you next apply power. It would be better however to continue the search for a replacement with lower, rather than higher, losses.

Answer (score 0):

This part is cheap and reasonably common in China. Your best bet if you're not planning on visiting soon is to ask the manufacturer or seller to send you some. They can buy them cheaply and will have them in hand in few days, getting them to you will be harder.

However, I don't want to get your hopes up- what you did was quite traumatic to the unit and other things may be blown up, starting with the power supply and maybe the driver parts, You may wish to purchase a new VFD and attempt the repair for a spare. Maybe the seller can throw the parts into the VFD package so shipping is free.

In the general question, if you pick an IGBT with at least as high voltage rating, at least as high current rating and similar gate charge (and package) you will probably be okay. Power rating should also be similar or higher, under the same conditions. Also look for special features such as integral co-packaged diode, short-circuit rating and so on. Some packages have overmolding so you don't need the silicone pads (but thermal paste is mandatory for good thermal performance). Incidentally, the silicone pads used in some of these low end products are quite inferior thermally.

Usually the gate drive voltage is nominally 15V or so, but transients may be greater so the gate rating might or might not be okay.

Substitution of stressed parts such as these involves quite a few considerations, and we don't know what the drive circuitry looks like so an exact replacement is safer.